# phpExcel reader long numbers to text

Tags: numbers, phpexcel

When reading a excel file, I have problems with numbers greater length:

I use:

```
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
$sheet      = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow     = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn  = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
  $obj = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
  list($CODE, $NAME) = $obj[0];
  echo $CODE;
}
```

And returns **1.6364698338384E+18**

Is it possible to obtain **1636469833838380000** ?

I try with

```
$CODE = (string) floatval($CODE);
```

... but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cell format to text in the excel file and then try reading the values from it.

Hope this helps.